# integration odoo with mobitel and orange payment gateway?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I am doing integration odoo with mobitel and orange money integration for pay bills.

i can't find the rest api's for integrate with those payment gateways

please anyone can help me and share me  for some documentation for integrating odoo with mobitel and orange payment gateway rest api's details or module if you have done worked before

Thanks,

Palani.

Answer (score 0):

Came across these, do these help ?

https://developer.orange.com/apis/om-webpay/

https://developer.mobitel.lk/mobitelint/mapis/product

have not used these payment gateways, but typically, one would need to register, get an account and then access the API.